# Putting parameters in a list and return them inside the definition with indexing

Tags: python-3.x, parameters, pygame, typeerror

I am making a game that can be played  with 1 to 3 players, Before the game starts the user is going to be asked how many persons are playing. The part i am struggling is displaying the right number of players on the screen.The idea that i came up with was as following. I created a `def` called `draw_text_2`, which prints the stats of the players on the correct position of the surface with the size and color of the text and the x and y position. Afterwards i put the parameters for draw text of each player inside a list.

```
player_1 = [100,0,0,0], player_2 = [100,0,0,0], player_3 = [100,0,0,0]



draw_text_2(surface, text, size, color, x, y):
   Draw text to surface
   surface - Pygame surface to draw to
   text    - string text to draw
   size    - font size
   color   - color of text
   x       - x position of text on surface
   y       - y position of text on surface









 player_display = [
[win,'Player 1     '+'Health: ' + str(player_1[0])+'  Damage:  ' + str(player_1[1])+'    Armour:  '+str(player_1[2])+'   postition: '+str(player_1[3]),10,(0,0,0),10,20]
[win,'Player 2     '+'Health: ' + str(player_2[0])+'  Damage:  ' + str(player_2[1])+'    Armour:  '+str(player_2[2])+'   postition: '+str(player_2[3]),10,(0,0,0),10,120]
[win,'Player 3     '+'Health: ' + str(player_3[0])+'  Damage:  ' + str(player_3[1])+'    Armour:  '+str(player_3[2])+'   postition: '+str(player_3[3]),10,(0,0,0),10,220]
]
```

So when the user inputs 2 `number of players for example`, the program is going to take out the parameters of the players for `draw_text_2` from `player_display` and put them inside of `draw_text_2` and since it is inside a while loop it will keep displaying because after the for loop is done `num_players_playing will` become 2 again. This did not work unfortunately, because it gave me a `TypeError` and `list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`. The question is how can i prevent this error to make this method and is there another way to this if the `TypeError` can't be solved?

```
while True:
       num_players_playing = 2
       while num_players_playing > 0:
             for i in player_display:
                 draw_text_2(i[x])
             num_players_playing -= 1
```

Comment: Please vote an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the error you are talking about comes from `draw_text_2(i[x])`. To prevent the error do make sure that you correct the code as suggested by the raised exception, and that is making sure that `x`, whatever `x` is, is an integer or a slice.

As for the game logic I think I'm seeing a bad pattern there. You have the `draw_text_2` method which for me kind of looks like you have a method for each variation of number of players which is essentially a bad practice. You want to make `draw_text` as generic as possible, and I'm not sure what is inside that function but what I recommend is that you should pass the number of players to the function as an argument and make some decisions inside the function based on that number.

I also see that you are doing `num_players_playing = 2`, though I'm assuming you want to let the players choose the number of players when the game starts and there is a number of ways to do this. I'm not familiar with PyGame but a classical approach to command line games would be to ask the user for the number of players like:

```
number_of_players = input("How many players?: ")
```